# c++ add variable value to string in one line

Tags: c++, string, exception, std

Is it possible to "easily" add variables to c++ string?

I want a behaviour similar to this

```
printf("integer %d", i);
```

but inside a string, specifically when throwing exception like this:

```
int i = 0;
throw std::logic_error("value %i is incorrect");
```

should be same as

```
std::string ans = "value ";
ans.append(std::atoi(i));
ans.append(" is incorrect");
throw std::logic_error(ans);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ doesn't work this way.

Comment: *String interpolation* is what it's generally called. C++20 will get a formatting library that works just like `std::printf`, but for strings.

Comment: will get or is already implemented? I am using g++9 which is compatible with c++20

Comment: @Hubert It is not C++20 compatible, because the C++20 standard hasn't even been finalized yet. The support is experimental against the current C++20 draft. That is why the command line option says `-std=c++2a`, not `-std=c++20`.

Comment: .According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2020), GCC's libstdc++ doesn't support c++2a text formatting yet.

Comment: @Hubert As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), none of the standard libraries support the text formatting additions for C++20 yet. (Search for "text formatting" on the page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options.

One is to use [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

auto test(int i)
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    throw std::logic_error{"value "s + std::to_string(i) + " is incorrect"s};
}
```

If you want more control over the formatting you can use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

auto test(int i)
{
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "value " << i << " is incorrect";

    throw std::logic_error{msg.str()};
}
```

There is work being done on a new standard formatting library. Afaik it is on track for C++20. It would go something like this:

```
#include <format>
#include <stdexcept>

auto test(int i)
{
    throw std::logic_error(std::format("value {} is incorrect", i)};
}
```

Comment: It would compile without `std::string_literals` as well

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica I see what you mean, but I like to be explicit, especially since `char[]` is a pesky type and you can do unwanted things like `"asdf" + 24`.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the `stringstream` STL class provided by the standard library. For your example it would be something like this:

```
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

std::stringstream ss;

ss << i << " is incorrect";
throw std::logic_error(ss.str());
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this *one line*

Comment: Fair point haha, but it would probably be a bit more versatile than string concatenation :)